# Changing label text of second ViewController upon clicking button on first ViewController without Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a serie of 10 questions to which people answer by pressing a button (3 choices). I would like to change the labels on the 2nd VC while they are scrolling through the test.

So far I've set my buttons in my first VC and this is where I do not know what code to write in order to change the label in the second VC:

```
@IBAction func levreun(_ sender: Any) {
    levrescore = 1
    print(levrescore, "sèches, gercées ou rouges")
}
```

(under print is what I want to send to the label on the second VC)

And this is how I prepared my label to be a String in the second VC:

```
@IBOutlet var LevreResultText: String!   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LevreResultText.text = LevreResultText
}
```

EDIT: Note that I do not want to perform a segue until the person presses COMPLETE at the end of the test. So the labels have to change while they answer the 10 questions!

Comment: Is second VC child on first ?

Comment: No they are 2 seperate view controllers.

Comment: Did you tried didSet and willSet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make static string variable in Second VC.
and when you tap button in first VC, you can change variable of static variable.

And In the ViewDidLoad function in Second VC, you can change label text as static variable.

First VC

```
@IBAction func levreun(_ sender: Any) {

    levrescore = 1
    print(levrescore, "sèches, gercées ou rouges")

    SecondVC.staticLabelText = "sèches, gercées ou rouges"
}
```

Second VC

```
static var staticLabelText = ""
@IBOutlet var LevreResultText: String!   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    LevreResult.text = 
    SecondVC.staticLabelText
}
```

Comment: I get the error: Type 'SecondVC' has no member 'staticLabelText' in the first VC

Comment: What is your SecondVC class name? you must use as "SecondVC class name".staticLabelText.

Comment: Here, SecondVC is class name, not variable.

Comment: oups I made a typo in my class name thanks! I'll give the build a try